# How to use "multiply" or "custom fn" aggregation in Vega Lite?

Tags: vega-lite

In example below the `mean` aggregation used. How to calculate aggregation as a multiplication of all the elements?

And, is it possible to use a custom JS function? Like `const myfn = (list) => list.length`, (I know there's a buit-in `count`, it's just to illustrate the idea).

[Playground](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvSl46I7HmKVAX3URIGIwGszkdjbUbIZCV4bk1GJWozUAhXAA8oyAAzRmQxTW8AYQBPCSVNZFs1KDwswmRvbiMwpXRTZw1XLIT0amojYTxynDdkdBVVKGTU9O6AQXh4VIKdHn7i0q6oAEdWPrxmGapIRw0dxyA)

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "Acceleration", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, product is not one of the [Built-in Aggregations](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/aggregate.html#ops) in Vega-Lite, and by design the schema does not support injecting arbitrary Javascript functions (it supports a limited [Vega Expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) syntax). Unless you preprocess your data before injecting into the Vega-Lite specification, you're limited to building your custom computation from the operations available there.

For your specific question, since the log of a product equals the sum of logs, one way you could compute the product within the specification is via a series of transforms like this ([playground](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvSl46I7HmKVAX3URIeI+iWwAZtyOozAG0NCANrMXhWMR1kM0gxbmoACm08VlQ6AEF4eGQxZA88HiUASjUodFg4hOpMyGcQsFAIForqaiNhPFicQINuQjjYdPLIb0Y8zWrEutUKqpx4xIB9QiNuTWW6xwBdF1aoDu5WQnYATyDIAGEziSVNAqqdxobWsPQIqJi45AAPQhSOnSdBqq3Wm0yZTmkEqcTWGy29Q0ew0kAwRgA1nF2DY1KjkEp4BtGEpqGZmi1IL9yWMJmIposbncHrZRngzoQelA-JoSR96vtXBd9LTJnDwYjoezOXEAI6sTxFXRFKhs5j5cUbJKQpEQRwgRxAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "log(datum.Acceleration)", "as": "logA"},
    {"aggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "logA", "as": "log_prod_A"}], "groupby": ["Cylinders"]},
    {"calculate": "exp(datum.log_prod_A)", "as": "prod_A"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "prod_A", "type": "quantitative", "title": "prod(A)"}
  }
}
```

[image]

A single bar dominates because there are many more entries with 4 Cylinders than with other numbers.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I was thinking about pre-processing, but this way the flexibility of on-the fly playing with VegaLite will be lost. So, I looked at sources, and it's turned out it's actually quite easy to add the `power` aggregation, there are only 2 changes needed one-line in `vega-lite` and 4 lines in `vega`.

Comment: That would be useful to have in the future, but for the time being I think the above approach (or something like it) is the only solution.